# What happens to fragments after the system kills an app?

Tags: android, fragment, state

"If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process.". When the user goes back to the activity, it restores it's state with a bundle.

My question is:

is it important to do this in oncreate:

```
if(savedinstance != null)
{
    fragement = fm.findFragmentByTag("tag");
}
else
{
    fragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.webViewFrame,fragment,"tag");
    ft.commit()
}
```

instead of just this:

```
    fragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.webViewFrame,fragment,"tag");
    ft.commit()
```

Comment: From my understandings, you should use the first one. The fragment could be already on the back stack. In this case, when you come back to the hosting activity, there is no need to get a new instance of the fragment, the one on the stack could be popped to show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are correctly saving the state of your activity and fragment in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and you want your activity to be recreated in the state it had before it was killed, you should use the first block of code you posted.

The `FragmentManager` saves its state, and when recreated, restores the fragments it was holding when the activity was killed. It steps them through the build-up lifecycle events using the fragment's saved state: create, createView, start, resume.

I'm pretty sure if you try running the second block of code, you will find after restart that you have two instances of your fragment in the `FragmentManager`--the one added when the activity was first create, and the one added after restart.

For this all to work correctly, you must carefully save the state of both your activity and fragment(s) in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method of each, and then in `onCreate()` test `savedInstanceState` and when not null, use the bundle to restore the state of your activity/fragment.

This is the guide for [saving/restoring activity state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: What if i don't want the fragmentmanager to keep the fragments when the activity is destroyed?

Comment: There are two cases: 1) activity is destroyed because of configuration change, such as device rotation 2) activity is destroyed, along with entire app process, because of memory pressure.  Do you want the fragments discarded in both cases or just 2)?

Comment: Follow-up to my previous comment:  Are you sure you want the fragment discarded when the activity is destroyed?  The intent of the Android multi-tasking design is that if an app is destroyed because of memory pressure, and then subsequently restarted from the Home screen or recent tasks display, the app is in the same state, and looks just as it did when it went into the background. Your users may be puzzled if your app restarts looking different.  If you want to discard the fragment because it has stale data, there may be better ways to do that.

Comment: @qbix What if I don't want the fragmentManager to keep the fragments when activity is destroyed due to configuration change?